# How Many Ways to Pick Objects : So That No One Picks the Exact Same Objects?

Tags: combinatorics, factorial, sampling

Suppose you have a set of:

- 5 Hats: H1, H2, H3, H4, H5
- 10 Pants: P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9, P10
- 6 Shoes: S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6

Suppose you have 3 Friends (F1, F2, F3).

- Each friend must at least pick one object
- Friends can pick similar combinations of objects
- However, no friend can have the exact same combination of objects as another friend
- After the 3 Friends have made their selections, items can still be left within the set

**How many "Legal" Combinations can be selected from this set?**

I have been trying to look at formulas that involve Factorials, Multinomial Theorem, Sampling With Replacement - but no formula seems to exactly match what I am trying to do.

Can someone please show me what formula needs to be used to solve this problem? And will there be a different formula if you want the set to be empty in the end?

Thank you!

Example of a Legal Combinations:

- F1:H1, H2, P1, S1, S2, S3
- F2: H1, H2, S1
- F3: P1, P5, S4, S5

Example of a Illegal Combinations: ( F2 = F3 )

- F1:H1, H2, P1, S1, S2, S3
- F2: H1, H2, S1
- F3: H1, H2, S1

Example of a Illegal Combinations: ( F1 contained in F2 )

- F1:H1, H2, P1, S1, S2, S3
- F2: H1, H2, P1, S1
- F3: H1, H2, S1

Comment: Hint:  use inclusion/exclusion.  How many ways can one friend select items?  Without the matching restriction, the answer would be the cube of this.  Now select the number of ways two friends can select the same items and finally account for all three selecting the same.

Comment: Thank you! These are new topics for me and I have never heard of them before!

Answer (score 1):

First, note that the type of items is irrelevant. Basically, there are 21 items.

Now expanding on the hint: Let us consider the case of two friends first. Friend 1 can select items in $n:=2^{21}-1$ ways, corresponding to the nonempty subsets of the set of total items. Call the set of ways as $A_1$. Friends 2 and 3 can similarly select items in $n$ ways also, denote the set of their ways as $A_2$ and $A_3$ (resp). By the product rule, the total number of ways the three friends can select items is $|A_1\times A_2\times A_3|=|A_1|\times |A_2|\times |A_3|=n^3$. This however includes the so-called 'illegal combinations' which must be subtracted now.

Clearly the number of ways of selections of friend $1, 2$ which are same are $n$ (as any of the $n$ selections can be identical). So there are $n$ illegal selections arising from selections of friends 1 & 2. Coupled with any of the $n$ selections of friend 3, by the product rule this means that there are $n^2$ illegal selections in which friend 1 and 2 choose identical items. Likewise there are $n^2$ illegal selections arising from friends 2,3 and there are $n^2$ illegal selections arising from friends 3 and 1. In total there are $3n^2$ illegal selections. We have however over-counted the illegal selections since we have included the $3n$ selections where all three pick the same items. These $3n$ selections arise in this fashion: In counting illegal selections of friends 1,2 we over counted $n$ selections where all three picked the same items, and likewise in the other two counts.  These $3n$ selections must be treated as $n$ distinct selections and so the total number of illegal combinations is $3n^2-3n+n=3n^2-2n$, and the final required value is $n^3-3n^2+2n$.