# General Theorems on Combinatorial Spaces

Tags: combinatorics

Are there any general theorems that indicate:

- Suppose a total number of "a" combinations can be made from objects in set "set 1"
- Suppose a total number of "b" combinations can be made from  objects in set "set 2"

Is there a total of "a*b" combinations that can be made if both of these sets were combined? Are there such theorems in math that make these kinds of statements on combinatorial spaces?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are saying follows from the fact that $|A\times B|=|A|\times |B|$, which is a consequence of the definition of the Cartesian product. Google the term 'product rule' for more information.

Comment: Thank you! Can this logic be applied here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427973/how-many-ways-to-pick-objects-so-that-no-one-picks-the-exact-same-objects